# Word VB: assigning shortcut key to macro template I made via VB script

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I re-assign/customize a specific shortcut key on my macro template. I want to re-assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to run my macro every time I hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> every time I open and use Microsoft Word.

*This will of course remove the default assignment of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to filesave command.
This will assign assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to run my macro template permanently.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your macro is MacroCtlS.  I recorded a macro (Word2003) doing "Tools", "Customize", "Keyboard", "Category/File/FileSave" un-assigning <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then "Category/Macros/MacroCtls", assigning <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>;.  But the recorded macro wasn't complete and I had to modify it.  Maybe later versions would do better.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
  Dim i1&
  CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
' delete existing binding
  FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeyS, wdKeyControl)).Disable
' add new binding
  KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyS, wdKeyControl), _
    KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="MacroCtlS"
' This is for extra credit.  But it doesn't list all KeyBindings?
  CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
  For i1 = 1 To KeyBindings.Count
    Selection.TypeText KeyBindings.Item(i1).Command & vbNewLine
  Next i1
End Sub
```